# Objecrtive C, overloading enum and float

Tags: objective-c, enums, overloading

I created the following category methods :

```
@implementation UIView (Snapshot)

enum ScaleType {FullScreen, RealSize};

- (UIImage *)captureSnapshot:(float)scale
{
   ...
}

- (UIImage *)captureSnapshot:(enum ScaleType)scaleType
{
    switch (scaleType) {
        case FullScreen:
            return [self captureSnapshot: 0.0f];
            break;

        case RealSize:
            return [self captureSnapshot: 1.0f];
            break;

        default:
            ...
    }
}

@end
```

This code does not compile with the error : "Duplicate declaration of method 'captureSnapshot:'
What is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot overload a method on parameter type in Objective-C. You need to give it a different name:

```
- (UIImage *)captureSnapshot:(float)scale;
- (UIImage *)captureSnapshotOfType:(enum ScaleType)scaleType;
```

This is because of the way methods are implemented in Objective-C: each method corresponds to a selector, and selector name does not depend on method's parameter types.